# $X^2_n \to 1$ in probability implies $X_n Y_n \to 1$ in probability for some $Y_n=\pm1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

I would like to prove the following proposition:

**Proposition.** Let $(X_n)$ be a random sequence and suppose that $X^2_n \to 1$ in probability. There exist a random sequence $(Y_n)$ with $Y_n=\pm1$ for each $n$ such that $X_n Y_n\to 1$ in probability.

I know the proposition is true for deterministic sequences, but how can I show it for a random sequence? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X_n^2 \to 1$ in probability implies $|X_n|\to 1$ in probability because the map $x \mapsto \sqrt{x}$ is continuous and $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$.

Next, define

$$Y_n:= I_{\{X_n \geq 0\}} - I_{\{X_n < 0\}}$$

Then $\operatorname{Im} Y_n \subseteq \{-1,1\}$ and  $|X_n| = X_n Y_n$ for all $n \geq 1$ and the result follows.

Comment: Great answer thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. Glad to help!